# Querying on two dbs with subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm have two mysql dbs:db_system and db_events, and
I need get the last event(db_events) for every device(db_system)

```
    SELECT * FROM db_events.events WHERE db_events.events.device_id IN (
            SELECT device_id 
            FROM db_system.devices 
            WHERE db_system.devices.vendor = 1)
    ORDER BY db_events.events.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

But I can't reach to get it, I'm only getting one record, I don't figure out how to get it, please can somebody help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If I remove LIMIT I'm getting a lot of records of every device, not the last for every one..and I need only the last for each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work using the `MAX(Id)` for each Device_ID:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM db_events.events e 
   JOIN (
      SELECT Max(id) MaxId, device_id
      FROM db_events.events
      GROUP BY device_id ) e2 on e.Id = e2.MaxId AND e.device_id = e2.device_id
WHERE e.device_id IN (
            SELECT device_id 
            FROM db_system.devices 
            WHERE vendor = 1)
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```

You probably don't need the ORDER BY any longer -- I just left it there in case that's how you wanted your results.

Also, this does assume that the Max(Id) is what determines your latest event for each device -- I'm assuming this since you were ordering by id DESC above.  If not, you can use a DateTime column instead with the same logic.

Comment: Hi @sgeddes I'm getting Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'db_events.events.device_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: @user1913878 -- I just copied your original query -- I edited my query above to use the table aliases instead -- see if that doesn't work :)

Comment: a last question, please, how can I Join to every result record a field of db_system.devices table? for example db_system.devices.brand??

Comment: @user1913878 -- sorry I just saw this (and your new question) -- are you just trying to join on devices instead of using in ?